# Entity Framework: can not update record because of validation issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public guid ProjectTypeId{ get; set; }
    public string projectType{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(125)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
    //more properties here
    //...
    public bool Activated{ get; set; }

    public IList<ProjectDetail> ProjectDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

A project has many details:

```
public class ProjectDetail
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectId{ get; set; }             
    public string DetailDescription{ get; set; }

    public IList<ProjectDetailsAnswer> ProjectDetailsAnswers{ get; set; }
}
```

What I try to do is to update just one field in a record

```
var ProjectInDb = _dbContext.Project.Where(.....).FirstOrDefault();

if (ProjectInDb == null) 
    return false;            

ProjectInDb.Activated = true;
ProjectInDb.DetailDescription = "updating this";         

var x = _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, when I execute the `_dbContext.SaveChanges()`, I get an error

> The User field is required.

I tried to fix it using this

```
_dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

but for some reason in my code I have a bug that sometimes updates the field and sometimes it does not..

How do I solve the error>The User Field is required.?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just remove the [Required] attribute from your model if it's not actually required?

Comment: I tried, but will it impact my index? or my navigation ?for instance if I use Eager load

Comment: I don't think it should have an effect and is probably necessary if the property isn't actually required.

Comment: all right , thanks . I tried and it worked, but I already have a problem. sometimes it is updated the field and sometimes not...I would say one time it doe so , and then it does not update